# Пройтись несколько раз по массиву и просчитать ходы

Tags: массивы, алгоритм

Добрый вечер, нужна подсказка для решения задачки:
Есть поле(массив) 3 на 3:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

К примеру я выбираю поле 7 и мне надо от 7 сделать 8 шагов вверх(или же вниз,влево,вправо) то есть если это вверх то будет такой ход: `4,1,8,5,2,9,6,3`
если рассматривать ситуацию от 7 вправо то будет так: `8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6` ну и тд.
Очень буду признателен за любой совет по тому как это реализовать, реализовывать буду на PHP но думаю здесь это не важно, так как нужен сам алгоритм решение можно даже на словах

Comment: Прямо вообще никаких идей нет? Про циклы Вы слышали?

Comment: та слышал решить можно только через них, но я пришел к тому что там надо делать 8 таких масивов и кучу проверок наверное это плохое решение

Comment: Вы хоть что-то попоробовали сделать?

Comment: да, но я ведь не прошу готового решение, а какой-то хороший подход к этому решению, то как я решил такой код нельзя показывать никому, поэтому вот надеюсь получить совет здесь

Comment: Попробуйте создать один масив только двухмерный. Ну а дальше если движетесь вправо, влево меняете один счетчик. А если вверх или вниз - другой

Comment: Если двигаться влево и дойти до начала строки, нужно перейти на следующую строку или предыдущую?

Comment: на предыдущую, а если это последняя строка сверху, то перейти на самую нижнюю строку и так по кругу, ходов может быть и больше

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(Как криворожанин жителю Днепропетровской области.)*

Вот одна из четырех функций. Три остальные будут отличаться направлениями движения (`++`/`--`), очередностью изменений `i` и `j` и проверками (не на длину, а на ноль).

```js
var arr = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9]
];

function goRight(arr, i, j, count) {
  var rows = arr.length;
  var cols = arr[0].length;
  var result = [];
  for (var k = 0; k < count; k++) {
    j++;
    if (j >= cols) {
      j = 0;
      i++;
      if (i >= rows) {
        i = 0;
      }
    }
    result.push(arr[i][j]);
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(goRight(arr, 2, 0, 8));
```

Comment: спасибо огромное!)